# 13 groups from different civ transported to 1 spot, How would they culturally react?

Tags: society, civilization

So in this cosmology I'm developing portals between worlds open from time to time and large numbers of one world can get stuck in another world. Earth is one of the worlds that are in this cosmology and such an event like this happens.

13 portals around Earth open up and about 10,000 people come through each of the portals. On the Prime World all 13 portals land to 1 place, depositing all the ~130,000 Earthlings in 1 place. All they have is what they were carrying or they dragged with them. So no house magically got pull through for example.

This happens about ~1000 BCE

These are the cultures that these people are pulled from:

1. The Zhou
2. The Olmec
3. Egyptians
4. Mesopotamians
5. The Greeks
6. Slavs
7. Celts
8. The Khmer
9. The Vedic Culture
10. The Adena Culture
11. The Maya
12. Jomon Culture
13. Teutonic Culture

These groups are all dropped in the same location which for reference is about 10 degrees south of the equator. There is a good size lake directly to the north. They can travel Northwest to about 10 degrees north of the equator. They're in the center (horizontally) of a region that is, from eyeing it, about the size of europe with a border west of mountains that are not impassible, but not an easy trek to get through. To the east, midway between them and the coast is an open mountain range. Other than the Northwesterly direction they are pretty close to the coast. To the South however they can get to about 50 degrees south before they hit a coast and mountains. The general climate of the region is of a forest.

The basic future history plan at this point is that these people spread out, colonize this area, an area past the western mountains, and a smaller continent to the north. There are other races that they'll run into in the future as they spread, but that doesn't matter at the moment. In fact neither does the above description of their surrounding, the area is big enough that they only really know they are in a forest with a Lake to the North and perhaps a coast to the north East within the time frame I care about for this question.

The question here is basically, What happens? How do these 13 groups react to each other and their situation? Which groups would likely ally? likely become enemies with? likely just quickly move away from this group? likely set up settlements? And which ones would come to dominate these settlements?

And for clarification I'm not asking "would Bob kill Susan." That's ultimately my decision. I'm asking, these are cultures that existed in history and they are known to have alliances, interactions, positions on foreigners so what would their take be on these other groups?

Also note, that while there is magic, monsters, and such in this world they would play no role in any of what would happen after the portal transports them. They would not run into any of that stuff within a few generations of this happening so it doesn't need to be taken into account.

---

Side Note: I realize that to answer this takes knowledge from that time period and of these cultures which most will only have or want to contribute partially, and not to mention the full answer will probably be really long, so feel free to answer for only the cultures you know about if you can't get all of them, and perhaps I can get the full answer from those partials.

Comment: I expect one of you people who voted to close this topic have a way to make this question not broad other than asking the same question 169 times for each combination which even if answered won't answer the overall question of how they all interact together.

Comment: I'm with Durakken here, this is a very good question that deserves whatever answer it can get. There are many possible answers, yet it is still clear to see how one could be selected as 'best'.

Comment: As far as I remember, questions that are worth being answered, but that can't be fully answered by one person, should be Community Wiki. Contact moderators for current rules. Otherwise, if it is impossible to post a full answer, it's too broad. Really long answers are pretty much *definition* of too broad close reason - compare last paragraph of the question with yellow bar under it.

Comment: @Mołot If I had the knowledge I could answer this in 13 short paragraphs (only because it's best to deal with each civ in a dif paragraph). There are questions that are far far far far longer than that many of them answered/asked by moderators so... that is just an excuse to be a dick rather than a legit reason not to answer a question from my perspective.

Comment: You could break this into thirteen questions, one for each culture.  Then each could be answered with thirteen or fewer sections.

Answer (score 2):

The Egyptians (my favorite, BTW) would be screwed.  They would be convinced that their rigid class system is the best and that everyone should adhere to it.  Unfortunately, without the Nile and the power that comes from being able to predict the floods, they have no power base with which to influence people.

Add the fact that they were hideously bad at war and they would go down soon.  They were protected by miles of desert on all sides.  Their idea of tactics was to arm all the farmers with pointed sticks or clubs, line them up and run at the enemy.  Meanwhile, the only effective weapons (bows and chariots) were reserved for the few nobles.

Every culture on you list that I know anything about would eat them for lunch.

The Greeks would conquer those they could and trade with those who do not look like an easy conquest.

Answer (score 2):

Do these people KNOW they are going? Because if you just scoop up 10K random folks from 13 places in 1000BCE and dump them all in an undeveloped forest somewhere, in 4 weeks you will have about 100 people left and all they are doing is eating the rest :P

The tech range of these groups is gonna vary wildly. If they knew where they were going so they could prepare and bring supplies and equipment, then probably the most militarily advanced group would dominate (maybe the Egyptians in this period, perhaps the Zhou?). But if it is just a cluster or even worse, random sampling, of 10K people across a culture then most everyone is gonna be screwed except some of the folks from whichever culture is most like the place they are ending up (and would presumably know how to extract a living from the area and might have the tools in order to do so).

Without pre-existing agriculture all of these folks are gonna die as soon as they eat up their supplies on hand. No way can the ecosystem there support 130K folks, even if they have the capability to fish out the lake and round up a big herd of bison or the equivalent.

In a forested area they are all basically dead. Very little to sustain them, especially in such numbers. EXPERIENCED and EQUIPPED teams, like the Lewis and Clark expedition could barely sustain themselves in wooded areas. 130K random folks from across the globe? No chance. They will strip every tree of its bark as they slowly starve to death after eating everyone else.

So environmental pressure is gonna be HUGE. The most militaristic groups are immediately going to prey on the physically weaker ones, kill them, and take their stuff. No group is going to be able to easily communicate with another, possible exception may be some members of geographically adjacent groups, like the European or American ones. But the likelihood of the right people getting together to mediate is very small unless these are carefully selected populations. Plus all the specific diseases these groups carry will run rife and wipe out most everyone anyway since no one is going to be immune to any of them.

Did they bring horses, etc? Without work animals the societies that rely on them are screwed. This will give an edge to cultures used to having only human labor. But the groups WITH draft animals will have an edge, at least until the horses starve for lack of feed/are slaughtered for food. There aren't many large mammals that live in forests and they are usually pretty spread out for a reason (food density is low).

It would also be a mistake to think that these groups would have solidarity WITHIN THEIR OWN GROUPS. 10K people is a lot, there will be many internal divisions. "Us versus them" will be the law, but "them" will include their own culture as well as all the others. Heck, half of these cultures wouldn't even consider the other half as intelligent humans, much less potential equals.

Their best (only) bet is to have time to prepare and bring supplies. Then have them arrive in late spring when there may be enough food around that they can supplement all that they bring with them. Then they may have time to clear land and start planting stuff, set up fishing sites, etc before winter. You say this is around the Equator so maybe there isn't any snow, but there will probably be some period of cooler, dryer weather since this is a forest and not a jungle, swamp, or desert. Cultures in this time period are almost all based around water so rivers and lakes are going to be hotly contested areas for settlements. Even then, I think most will be dead.

Your only real solution is to have a pre-existing, benevolent society already there willing to help these guys out. Or be raided for stuff, as that is probably the more likely possibility. Then you may relieve the pressure of day to day survival enough for groups to cooperate and work together. Even then I don't see much shared commonality across cultures unless some can monopolize a needed resource, protect it, and then set up a system of barter/trade that forces communication. The more advanced societies like the Egyptian and Zhou can certainly do this, these groups (there may be others, I'm not as familiar with some of them) all have well developed systems for writing and are comfortable with things like trade deals, envoys, and general diplomacy. I'm not sure a group of Celts, for example, would be able to, or even WANT to, unite in a way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

This will be short. Dumping 130,00 human beings in effectively one spot means that their principal cultural reaction will be culinary. Finding enough to eat and finding ways of preparing and cooking their food.

Those from cultures best suited to surviving the wild will thrive (in relative terms). Mostly this depend on how those who passed through the portals were chosen. Alternatively they may have been siphoned by the portals and simply dumped at the other end. The question is specific on this point.

Initially they won't be building a civilization or planning military campaigns, they will be trying to survive. Food, shelter and safety will be uppermost in their minds. How they come out of those dilemmas will shape the culture they make afterwards. Remember people adapt to their circumstances. They abandon anything of their old culture(s) that isn't useful for their survival.

Answer (score 0):

It happened already many times in the history, that significantly different cultures lived together.

They didn't like the others, all of them has seen the others as uncivilized, ugly beings. The only reason for them to not exterminate ("civilize") the others was that they weren't enough powerful for that. If they were enough powerful, the fate of the weakers were

- a lost war
- slavery
- finally cultural assimilation.

The main rules of the politics are everywhere the same. Thus, the kings would know, what to do.

I predict a chaotic situation, with many conflicts, alliances and treasons.

The ultimate end will be that one of the civilizations would enslave and assimilate all of the others after a series of wars.

Comment: Yes, i need to know generally which ones would do what with which ones and which likely raises up and which falls generally. I can take a guess on some of it, but I don't know enough about them all to really say and there are key factors like Egypt is used to the Nile Valley where as this is a forest so that may cause huge issues.

Comment: @Durakken It is a highly chaotic thing, like as nobody knows which parties will rule your country 3 elections later. Thus I have only ideas: 1) the technologically more developed civilizations have *much* more chance. Considering that in the late stone/early bronze age there weren't such a big technological difference, it is probably not such an important thing as today. 2) The most centralized, and most militarized civilizations would have also a much higher chance. Although I don't know them enough well to compare them in this view.

Comment: I know that... I'm asking about these specific cultures v.v and these cultures range from Stone Age to Early Iron Age...

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking the Slavs, Celts, and Teutons have some fights that might lead to some uneasy truces and they head for the foothills, probably to the south into cooler climes.  They may have problems with each other, but they will probably eat just about anybody else's lunch in a fight in the forest.  They Mayans are probably going to handle the jungle fairly well.  I don't know enough about the other cultures to guess too much beyond other answers.

You are pulling from far enough back in history that we don't have any sources to rely on, only conjecture from what we know about those cultures when they rubbed up against someone who was writing things down.  If you extrapolate from the relative climates that these people came from, you might see how the new culture might develop.  for Example, the Celts and the Teutons didn't do much with organized warfare, but they prized individual bravery.

Egyptians, Greeks, and Persians all had a highly structured military but they tended toward inflexibility.  That was an advantage in wide open spaces, but not as great in the forests where the Teutons and Celts were.

I'm lumping in the Slavs with the Teutons and Celts just because of the mountainous terrain, which should produce a similar value system.

You can do a lot of educated guesses if you look at the climate and terrain where these peoples come from as it had major impacts on the cultures.  The new climate and terrain will also shape what direction they take.